# Find the value of $\theta$ in parallelogram $ABCD$.

Tags: geometry, angle

**Question:**

> If $ABCD$ is a parallelogram then find the angle $\theta$ in degrees.
> [image]

*What I tried:*

I assumed $BD$ a straight line as I don't think this question can be solved if $BD$ is not a straight line.(I will be happy if someone solves this without this assumption)

**Construction:** Drew $EF$ perpendicular to ($CD$ and $AB$) and $GH$ to ($BC$ and $AD$).
[image: Fig 1]

$$\angle DAO=\angle DCO=y$$ Alternate interior angles:$$\angle BDA=\theta\\\angle ABD=40^\circ$$

By Angle Sum Property:
$$\angle DOG=90^\circ-\theta\\\angle GOA=90^\circ-y\\\angle AOF=70^\circ\\\angle FOB=50^\circ\\\angle BOH=90^\circ-\theta\\\angle HOC=70^\circ\\\angle COE=90^\circ-y\\\angle EOD=50^\circ$$
Adding all these and equating to $360^\circ$:
$$240^\circ+360^\circ-2\theta-2y=360^\circ$$
$$\theta+y=120^\circ$$

After this, I drew parallel lines to ($AD$ and $BC$) and ($AB$ and $CD$) through $O$ but didn't get the value of $\theta$.

How to solve this question?
Can this be solved?

Thanks!

Comment: [Original question image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Q5IP.jpg)

Comment: If $BD$ is a straight line, then $\triangle ABD \cong \triangle CBD$ and $\theta=40^\circ$.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I said.

Comment: @Tavish How $\triangle ABD \cong \triangle CBD$?

Comment: @Tavish I think by that condition $\triangle ABD \cong \triangle CDB$ , not $\triangle ABD \cong \triangle CBD$.

Comment: Then I think Tavish has made a mistake.

Comment: It is true that $AO=OC$, $OB=OB$ and the $20º$ angles are equal, but that does not give us enough information to determine if they are congruent. You can verify that $\theta = 40º$ using GeoGebra, but there needs to be proper justification.

Comment: @TobyMak How $AO=OC$?

Comment: That’s right YouKnowMe, $ABD$ and $CDB$ are congruent. This follows from the theoreM that states a diagonal of any parallelogram divides it into two congruent triangles.

Comment: Extending AO and CO seems to give $\angle AOD=60^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assumption is not necessary. Construct $P$ on the parallel to $AB$ by $O$ such that $PAD\cong OBC$. Then $\angle PDA = 20°$, but $\angle POA = \angle OAB = 20 °$, so $AODP$ is cyclic. But then $\angle CBO = \angle DAP = \angle DOP = \angle CDO = 40°$.

[image]

Comment: Clever and elegant af

Comment: How $AODP$ is cyclic?

Comment: Pick any point U on line DC left of D and any point V on line AB left of A. Let DA and PO intersect at K, then KPA=PAV and UDP=DPK=DAO. $\theta+20^{\circ}+PAV+DAO=180^{\circ}$.

Comment: $\angle PDA = \angle POA$ also implies $AODP$ is cyclic. This is converse of angles in the same segment.

Comment: @Divide1918 Thanks  

Answer (score 2):

The following solution assumes $BD$ is a straight line.

Extend $AO$ such that it intersects $BC$ at $X$, and extend $CO$ such that it intersects $AB$  at $Y$. Then $\angle AOY+\angle OAB=\angle OYB=\angle OCB+\angle CBA\implies \angle AOY=\angle COX=100^{\circ}-\theta$. Then $\angle AXB=120^{\circ}-\theta$, and angle sum in $\triangle BOX$ gives $\angle BOX=\angle AOD=60^{\circ}$. So $\angle COB=160^{\circ}-\theta$.

Let the height $EF$ be as in OP's attempt. Suppose that $OE:OF=m:n$. By similar triangles, $OE:OF=DO:BO=CO:OY=CD:BY=AO:OX=AD:BX=m:n$, and  $CO:AO=OX:OY=CX:AY$ since $\triangle COX \sim \triangle AOY$. Now, $CO:OY=AO:OX\implies CO:AO=OY:OX$, but $CO:AO=OX:OY$, so $OY:OX=OX:OY\implies OX^2=OY^2\implies OX=OY$. Hence $AO=CO$ and $\triangle BOC\cong\triangle BOA$.

Thus $\theta=40^{\circ}$.